# An incomprehension about geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance Message

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a question about pose covariance.

In the doc website ([link text](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovariance.html)), I see the covariance is shown as a matrix with 6*6 size and the parameters are x, y, z, rotation about X axis, rotation about Y axis, rotation about Z axis in order.

I am confused about the size and the parameters. The x,y,z are the coordinate of a 3D point and they are 3 parameters? And then, three rotations are shown in 3*3 matrix respectively? If it is, the all parameters are 3 + 3*9 = 30. Why 6*6 here?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345141/an-incomprehension-about-geometry_msgs/posewithcovariance-message/) by [YancenBOB](https://answers.ros.org/users/44257/yancenbob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2020-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is 6x6 because it is a covariance matrix with the 6 different states ( x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw). The diagonal of this matrix is the variance ( the  "spread" of a specific state, e.g. a high x position variance means it has  a very large spread of values), the other values will be the "covariance" with respect to the other 5 states. If it is a pure diagonal matrix it means there is no covariance between the states.

https://datascienceplus.com/understanding-the-covariance-matrix/

---

Originally posted by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) with karma: 525 on 2020-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [YancenBOB](https://answers.ros.org/users/44257/yancenbob/) on 2020-03-01**:
Thanks for your answer. By the way, I guess that the TwistWithCovariance is about the linear velocity of xyz and the rotation velocity about 3 axes?

**Comment by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) on 2020-03-02**:
Exactly. Just derive everything once.

**Comment by [YancenBOB](https://answers.ros.org/users/44257/yancenbob/) on 2020-03-04**:
Ok, I got it. Thanks you!